# How to perform the $2\pi$ pulse in the two-ion Cirac-Zoller CNOT gate?

Tags: ion-trap-quantum-computing, trapped-ion, logical-gates

When implementing the [Cirac-Zoller CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirac%E2%80%93Zoller_controlled-NOT_gate) between two ions $A$ and $B$, the **second step** of the procedure changes the sign of the second ion when the ion is in its ground state $|0_B\rangle$ and the ion lattice is in its first excited state $|1_z\rangle$ and leave any of the other possible states unchanged. This step is called the $2\pi$-pulse. I know that a rotation gate $R_x(2\pi)$ changes the global sign of the qubit state. However, I can't see how it can take into account the state of the lattice vibration.

The first step has a similar procedure, acting on qubit $A$. In that step, it is easy to see why the other states are not affected because the red-detuned laser only allows for the specific transition $|1_A,0_z\rangle \leftrightarrow |0_A,1_z\rangle$.

How is this sort of controlled $R_x(2\pi)$ doing the "controlled" part?

PS: Apparently this can be done using a third qubit state in a way that is not really clear to me which was explained in this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-does-a-2-pi-pulse-in-cirac-zoller-give-a-1-sign-to-the-state). Can it be done in a different way?